# Make "priority" number unique in a database table using only SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

We have a database table that looks like this:

```
RowID   CustomerID  Priority    Data
11      123         1           {some data}
2       123         1           {some data}
3       123         3           {some data}
44      456         1           {some data}
5       456         2           {some data}
61      456         2           {some data}
65      456         2           {some data}
76      456         2           {some data}
96      456         3           {some data}
36      456         4           {some data}
7       123         1           {some data}
```

It's a list of items that are supposed to be sorted by priority.  Unfortunately, due to a system error (both code and improper constraints), some of the priorities were duplicate.

For instance, in the example I gave, customer 456 has three items with priority `2`.  Unfortunately, there is no way at this point to know which one was actually supposed to be in slot `2`.

Obviously, the system needs to be corrected to prevent this situation (and this is being done), but we still need to resolve the customer data situation.  In this example, if we were focused on just fixing customer #456's data, the best solution we have been able to come up with is to change 456's rows to look like this:

```
RowID   CustomerID  Priority    Data
44      456         1           {some data}
5       456         2           {some data}
61      456         3           {some data}
65      456         4           {some data}
76      456         5           {some data}
96      456         6           {some data}
36      456         7           {some data}
```

You can see that priorities were incremented as follows:

- Row 61 was incremented by 1,
- Row 65 was incremented by 2,
- Row 76 was incremented by 3,
- Row 96 was incremented by 3,
- Row 36 was incremented by 3

This restores the data to a situation where no two items share the same priority.

I'm wondering if there is a way to address this solution in SQL, or if I'm going to have to write a "fix-it" program that analyzes the database one customer at at time.

Try as I might, I can't seem to wrap my mind around how this could be accomplished in straight SQL.  Is it possible?

Comment: Yes it can be accomplished in straight mySQL. see my answer, read it carefully, as I think you might want to run the last query, since you only want to fix data for customer 456

Comment: In my example, I was updating things only for customer 456, but that was just for the sake of my example where I was manually specifying, in a bulleted list, what would change.  But I wanted SQL that would update everybody, and what you provided worked great, although I did have to read it over a few times to understand it :-)  Thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to order by customerId,priority,rowId and set priority to 1,2,3,4...and so on for each customer like the queries below

first to see if the newPriority is what you want for each row do ([sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1dd637/4/0))

```
   SELECT rowId,customerId,priority
       IF(@prevCustomer <> customerId,@priority:=1,@priority:=@priority+1)
          AS newPriority,
       @prevCustomer:=customerId
   FROM YourTable,
        (SELECT @priority:=0,@prevCustomer:=0)dummy
   ORDER BY customerId,priority,rowId
```

then if that's correct, check the newPriority column and see, you can run the UPDATE below ([sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9bfbe/1/0))

```
UPDATE yourTable T1
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT rowId,customerId,priority
       IF(@prevCustomer <> customerId,@priority:=1,@priority:=@priority+1)
          AS newPriority,
       @prevCustomer:=customerId
   FROM YourTable,
        (SELECT @priority:=0,@prevCustomer:=0)dummy
   ORDER BY customerId,priority,rowId
  )T2
ON T1.rowId = T2.rowId
SET T1.priority = T2.newPriority;
```

**To only fix customer 456** you can add `WHERE T1.customerId=456` at the end of query like below

```
UPDATE yourTable T1
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT rowId,customerId,priority,
       IF(@prevCustomer <> customerId,@priority:=1,@priority:=@priority+1)
          AS newPriority,
       @prevCustomer:=customerId
   FROM YourTable,
        (SELECT @priority:=0,@prevCustomer:=0)dummy
   ORDER BY customerId,priority,rowId
  )T2
ON T1.rowId = T2.rowId
SET T1.priority = T2.newPriority
WHERE T1.customerId = 456;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you put any SQL in a transaction, then select all rows to visually see if its what you want. Then rollback. Only when you are sure its correct, change it to a commit. This way, you don't corrupt your database data. Alternately (and better) backup your database so you can restore it if you mess up. The disadvantage is that any customer changes to the database after you backup will be lost if you need to do a restore.